# Expanding a JSON column in Pandas

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I have an Excel sheet with a column containing a JSON object similar to the below (there is always at least one item). Is there a way to expand out this column with Pandas? There is explode function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html which seems to do the work (structure wise) but it doesn't have a special treatment for JSON.

```
[
   {
      "id":1234,
      "title":"SSL Certificate - Signature Verification Failed Vulnerability",
      "rating":"medium",
      "status":"Active"
   },
   {
      "id":5698,
      "title":"SSL Certificate - Subject Common Name Does Not Match Server FQDN",
      "rating":"low",
      "status":"Active"
   }
]
```

I also tried a for loop to achieve this, which was fine until I could not find a way to concat my normalized JSON output to the "current row":

```
for index, row in filtered.iterrows():
    findings = row["MyJSON_COLUMN"]   
    pd.json_normalize(findings)
```

Comment: How working `pd.json_normalize(filtered["MyJSON_COLUMN"])` ?

Comment: @jezrael what do you mean? I expand every column in this loop and append the data frames?

Comment: Yes, if possible, hard to know hoa all data looks, is possible share it by `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should actually use `read_json` instead of `json_normalize`. Go about it the following way. Take all your strings, save them is a json file

```
{"id":1234,"title":"SSL Certificate - Signature Verification Failed Vulnerability","rating":"medium","status":"Active"}
{"id":5692,"title":"SSL Certificate - Subject Common Name Does Not Match Server FQDN","rating":"low","status":"Active"}
```

One of your strings for each line. I save it as testingread.json, and run this

```
pd.read_json(r"..../testingread.json", lines=True)
```

Note the `lines = true`.

[image]

Comment: The JSON content is a column in an Excel sheet, it describes findings in the parent record. I am trying to expand these finding while copying parent record. That is why I was using the json_normalize instead.